# how to request this API using python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, python-requests

API is :http://sapi.genshuixue.com/area/getCityListV2

in chrome loading this api, response is :

{"message":"\u7cfb\u7edf\u7e41\u5fd9\uff0c\u8bf7\u7a0d\u540e\u91cd\u8bd5!","code":0,"result":{"message":"\u7b7e\u540d\u5931\u6548"}}

but i use fiddler can get the response json successfully.

in the fiddler,the headers is :

```
POST /area/getCityListV2 HTTP/1.1
Host: sapi.genshuixue.com
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 1481
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=Boundary+BD495D1B844800CF
Accept-Language: zh-Hans-CN;q=1
Cookie: AUTH_TOKEN=A34lZ2l6bWhqZG9qKEE6PT8_PEI6NSx_fXB9f4V8cS9HOj86MHB_f2-EiYF2M0xEPjV2hzZORUlKRkZIS05JSEQ6i3qFjTxUPFyMTV1PgZVNP5s; CITY_ID=117964800; CITY_NAME=%E5%AE%89%E9%A1%BA; PHPSESSID=8qb1qcjdg2j6sijvqdr9k2ut26; __guid__=567d13599d81f5-63960182; __track_id__=567d13584ce54948918369f2be2f9af477819b03; _ga=GA1.2.1164903637.1451037531; device_no=82B44270-909C-4213-AC3D-AF328895F335; jailbroken=0; lat=0; lng=0
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: BJEducation_student/3.0.5 (iPhone; iOS 9.2; Scale/2.00)
```

Question is :

**HOw could i use python requests modules to get the response ?**

i use:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
params = {
        'Host': 'sapi.genshuixue.com',
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
        'Accept': '*/*',
        'Accept-Encoding':'gzip',
        'Content-Length': 1481 ,
        'Content-Type':'multipart/form-data',
        'boundary':'Boundary+3124969C679D964B',
        'Accept-Language': 'zh-Hans-CN;q=1',
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
        'User-Agent': 'BJEducation_student/3.0.1 (iPhone; iOS 9.2; Scale/2.00)',
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
        }
cookie= {
        'AUTH_TOKEN':'A34lZ2l6bWhqZG9qKEE6PT8_PEI6NSx_fXB9f4V8cS9HOj86MHB_f2-EiYF2M0xEPjV2hzZORUlKRkZIS05JSEQ6i3qFjTxUPFyMTV1PgZVNP5s',
        'CITY_ID' : '503578624',
        'CITY_NAME' : '%E6%9D%AD%E5%B7%9E',
        'device_no' : '82B44270-909C-4213-AC3D-AF328895F335',
        'jailbroken' : '0',
        'lat' : '0' ,
        'lng' : '0' ,
        }
df = requests.post('https://sapi.genshuixue.com/area/getCityListV2',headers=params,cookies = cookie,verify=False)
```

it  fails

Comment: Read the requests documentation. It will tell you how to do it: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/

Comment: POST requests generally have a body. Where's your body in your Requests  request?

Comment: how to find the body  in fiddler?   i use the fiddler graped the api。